# accessibility on WKWebView on first launch

Tags: swift, accessibility

I have a WKWebView and I would like to add accessibility. The only problem is when the page loads up the first time, accessibility focus is lost on the buttons in the page but if I use my finger to tap the screen, then focus comes on. How can I enable focus on selection of the Webview

```
import WebKit
class ViewControllear: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        
        let myWebView:WKWebView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height:UIScreen.main.bounds.height))
        myWebView.uiDelegate = self
        self.view.addSubview(myWebView)
        
        
        //1. Load web site into my web view
        let myURL = URL(string: "https://www.apple.com")
        let myURLRequest:URLRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
        myWebView.load(myURLRequest)
        
    }
    
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [`becomeFirstResponder()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621113-becomefirstresponder) -

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    
    let myWebView:WKWebView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height:UIScreen.main.bounds.height))
    myWebView.uiDelegate = self
    self.view.addSubview(myWebView)
    
    
    //1. Load web site into my web view
    let myURL = URL(string: "https://www.apple.com")
    let myURLRequest:URLRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
    myWebView.load(myURLRequest)
    myWebView.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```